# Remove anything after . (dot). Including dot

Tags: powershell, split

```
subdomain1.google.nl
subdomain1.subdomain2.google.com
subdomain1.facebook.com
subdomain1.subdomain2.facebook.com
```

How can i (by Powershell) remove the topleveldomain (TLD) so my results will be:

```
subdomain1.google
subdomain1.subdomain2.google
subdomain1.facebook
subdomain1.subdomain2.facebook
```

Comment: `'subdomain1.subdomain2.facebook.com' -replace '\.[^.]*?$'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cat try regex patterns OR you could try this:

```
$string = 'subdomain1.google.nl'
[io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($string)
```

Output:

```
subdomain1.google
```

Actually! I was so curious about what would be the best perfomance wise method and guess what:

```
$results = @()
for ($i=1;$i -le 1000;$i++){
    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Execution #' -Value $([int]$i)
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'IOPath_Ticks' -Value $(Measure-Command -Expression {[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension('subdomain1.google.nl')} | Select -ExpandProperty Ticks)
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Regex_Ticks' -Value $( Measure-Command -Expression {'subdomain1.google.nl' -replace '\.[^.]*?$'} | Select -ExpandProperty Ticks)
    $results += $obj
}
```

Average

```
$results  |  Measure-Object -Property IOPath_Ticks  -Average

Count    : 1000
Average  : 129,978
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : IOPath_Ticks

$results  |  Measure-Object -Property Regex_Ticks  -Average
Count    : 1000
Average  : 364,56
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : Regex_Ticks
```

Sum

```
$results  |  Measure-Object -Property IOPath_Ticks -Sum
Count    : 1000
Average  : 
Sum      : 129978
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : IOPath_Ticks

$results  |  Measure-Object -Property Regex_Ticks -Sum
Count    : 1000
Average  : 
Sum      : 364560
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : Regex_Ticks
```

So, as you can see when you need to process a big number of records usage of .NET Classes would do best compare to regexes

Comment: Creative abuse of static methods FTW. ;)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, true! I have a little testings, check out the numbers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try as:

```
$val="subdomain1.google.nl"
$val.substring(0,$val.LastIndexOfAny("."))
$val="subdomain1.subdomain2.google.com"
$val.substring(0,$val.LastIndexOfAny("."))
$val="subdomain1.facebook.com"
$val.substring(0,$val.LastIndexOfAny("."))
$val="subdomain1.subdomain2.facebook.com"
$val.substring(0,$val.LastIndexOfAny("."))
```